Why does echo Hi | base64, in a Linux shell, give "SGkK" instead of "SGk="? Does the shell automatically add a \n to the end of Hi?
Hi in binary is 01001000 01101001, so to pad it to 24-bits you have to add 00000000, which breaks up into 4 6-bit sequences as 010010 000110 100100 000000, which in the RFC 468 Base64 alphabet is SGk=, and not SGkK. But Hi\n in binary is 01001000 01101001 00001010, which encodes to SGkK.

The shell doesn't do this, echo does. Use printf to print without adding a newline.

Just type echo Hi and you'll see that the shell prompt is on the next line. Compare with printf Hi.
